# How to find kth smallest element in an array based BST? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I was given this as a task, but this is seemingly very very difficult for me.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<A extends Comparable<? super A>> {

public int[] size
public Object[] list

public A get(int x) {
}

}
```

```
    7
   / \
  5   10
 / \  / \
3   6 9 11

The above tree would be stored as [7, 5, 10, 3, 6, 9, 11] in the list array.
```

So I have this structure.
I have to find the x-th smallest element by using the sizes of the subtrees.
I am clueless on how to first find the sizes of the subtrees and then use that information in order to find the x-th value.

Does anyone have an approach? I've been trying for multiple days but even the web is not giving me much information.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: is this a BST? the structure you were given is a generic tree

Comment: Yes, it is a BST. I will change the code to make it more obvious.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not a place for people to complete your homework assignments for you.

Comment: No, it isn't. And I'm not asking for someone to give me copy and paste code. I'm asking a bunch of knowledgable people for help on how to approach a problem for such a unique tree. But thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are no nodes with single child?

Comment: No, the tree can have single childs.

Comment: I think the answers have covered it well, but if you didn't have to solve it using the sizes of the subtrees, the visitor pattern would be a good choice for a solution. In short, create an object, the visitor, which has count k, and pass it into an in-order traversal. At each step in order, pass it the next value ("visit" the node). It counts down and picks the correct kth value. Also, at each step, ask it if it is satisfied (if it has found the kth element). If so, all remaining recursive calls can just return and you can get the kth value out of the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that BSTs are sorted. The underlying array isn't, but if you traverse the tree in a certain way (left for you to find out), you will get every element in ascending order. If you do manage to find out how to do this, you need only look until you reach your nth element.

I suppose you could figure it out using the sizes of the subtrees, but that sounds needlessly complicated (that is, the code would be less readable, the math isn't too hard) and impractical in real life. BSTs exist for a reason, after all.

It is possible to do with sizes. Imagine you start at the root. Let L be the size of your left subtree, and R the size of your right. Your total amount of nodes will be L + R + 1. Your root will have index L, if x is larger than L, you know that you will find your element in the right subtree, if it's smaller, then look in your left. (Assuming x is null-indexed). This is the general pattern, you can probably figure out the rest for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, this is an answer which is helpful. I understand an inorder traversal is needed to print the nodes in an ascending order, and from there it would be easy, but this task specifically requires me to store the sizes of each subtree into an array, and then use the sizes of each subtree to get the k-th element which I understand is impractical irl.

Comment: I updated it with a new hint. Remember that the left subtree contains the first `SIZE(left)` # of nodes, and that the right one contains the last `SIZE(right)` # of them. You should be able to apply the general idea of this for all subtrees, but remember to take into account the index of your root each time. Whenever you continue on a new subtree, you're dealing only with the first and last elements of _that_ particular subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive method size(tree) to compute the size of a node of the tree.

```
size(tree) {

  if tree == null
    return 0;
  return 1 + size(tree.left) + size(tree.right)

}
```

Given a tree, find the kth element (starting with k=1) like this:

```
find(tree, k) {

  let left_size = size(tree.left)
  let current_index = left_size + 1

  if k == current_index
    return tree
  if k > current_index
    return find(tree.right, k - current_index)
  else
    return find(tree.left, k)

}
```

Summary:
If you have k-1 items on your left, then your current position is item k.

If your current position is less than k, then search the right tree, but reduce your search index by the index of the current node (left_size + 1), which includes the item at the current node and all the items in the left tree.

If your current position is greater than k, then search the left tree for item k.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `constant space` and `linear time`.

There's this traversal called Morris Inorder Traversal

You can just keep a **counter** and **break** your loop once you meet the **desired** count.